# What regex expression would i use for 07X XXXX XXX as a number?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a phone number that i want the figures 07 to be constants then the rest should be regex?

Mine looks like this: `/^\07(?([0-9]{1})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/`.

Example Number: 0752 8182 12

Comment: Try tools like Regexr and see how you you get there too.

Comment: Really `(?`? Did you miss the ``\`` before the parentheses? Also, `\07` is parsed as an octal value, remove that ``\``.

Comment: can you give some example numbers you are looking to match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest fixing your pattern as

```
/^07\(?([0-9])\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{4})[-. ]?([0-9]{3})$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HRuHV1/1)

You missed the `\` before the first `(` and the backslash with `\07` made the regex engine parse the `07` part as an octal value.

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `07` - `07`
- `\(?` - an optional `(` (**note** that you need to remove it together with `\)?` if you do not want to allow values like `07(5) 4444 333`)
- `([0-9])` - a digit (the `(` and `)` may be removed if you do not need to get the captured subtext)
- `\)?` - an optional `)`
- `[-. ]?` - an optional `-`, `.` or space
- `([0-9]{4})` - 4 digits (same note about parentheses)
- `[-. ]?` - ibid
- `([0-9]{3})` - 3 digits (same note about parentheses)
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 1):

I cleaned up your regex some, you don't need to have those extra parentheses in unless you are doing something with groups:

```
/^07\(?[0-9]\)?[-. ]?[0-9]{4}[-. ]?[0-9]{3}$/
```

would match these numbers

```
071 1111 111
077.1151.111
071-3211-121
0711111111
07(1) 1111 111
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide examples of valid and invalid numbers, I am guessing based on your regex.  Try this:

```
var numbers = [
    "0701234123",
    "070 1234 123",
    "070-1234-123",
    "070.1234.123",
    "07(0)1234-123",
    "07(0) 1234-123",
    "0070 1234 123",
    "070 123 1234"
];

//var pattern = /^07\(?([0-9]{1})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;
var pattern = /^07\(?\d\)?[-. ]?\d{4}[-. ]?\d{3}$/;
//   /d = [0-9]
var matched = numbers.map(function (number) {
    var matches = number.match( pattern );
    if (matches) {
        console.log(number + " valid");
    } else {
        console.log(number + " invalid");
    }
});
```

Output is:

```
0701234123 valid
070 1234 123 valid
070-1234-123 valid
070.1234.123 valid
07(0)1234-123 valid
07(0) 1234-123 valid
0070 1234 123 invalid
070 123 1234 invalid
```